# How to fix clock multiplier, it is 8x with 100 MHz Bus speed?

Tags: performance, bios, hp-pavilion, bus, cpu-z

May laptop ([HP G7](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-g7-1300-Notebook-PC-series/5186814/model/5242963/solutions?sku=A7A43UA)) which is a low end laptop but can can overloaded even multiple tabs. I have seen it loading very slow if I search images on google search.

I recently installed CPU-Z and found that the bus speed is 100 MHz. I thought that could be the reason it is slow. I search online and tried to check BIOS setting if I can change anything. Unfortunately the BIOS that comes with G7 is just rudimentary with literally nothing changeable (configuration wise).

Does anyone know if I can something to decrease multiplier so my speed goes higher may be 400MHz? Or it is just the wrong setting shown in CPU-Z? What is your experience with it?

[Result of CPU-Z of my laptop is here](http://valid.x86.fr/0pqawq)

Comment: change the Windows powerplan to balanced or high performance.

Comment: should i restart my pc then?

Comment: now the muliplier has gone from 8x to 20x [see cpuz result](http://valid.x86.fr/fs8z49)

Comment: this is fine now and it should be faster now.

Comment: is the question now answered?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I looked at my office PC which is high end core i5(4th gen) and that one also show 100Mhz bus speed so not sure if this is just the cpu-z error.

Comment: 100Mhz is fine. The multiplier of only 8 was the cause of the slow Windows

Comment: Hmm I thought bus speed should be 800Mhz or so?

Comment: nope, the bus speed is the same, the higher frequency comes from a higher CPU multiplier. 8x is the lowest to save most power.

Answer (score 0):

The 800MHz look like Windows runs in power saving mode which locks down the frequency to this low value to save power.

To allow high clock rates, [change the powerplan of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-create-delete-power-plan-scheme#1TC=windows-7) to `balanced` or `high performance`.